# UNION ALL returns a top 1 result incorrect only in SQL Server 2017

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Recently upgrading from SQL Server 2016 to 2017 I came across a odd bug, I narrowed it down to:

```
select top 1 * from (
    select top 1 id from [user]
    union all
    select 0
) a
```

Now if I run this in SQL Server 2016 I get

> 1

If I run it in 2017 I get

> 0

If I change the `select top 1 *` to `select *` I get

> 1
>
> 0

In both SQL Server 2016 and 2017...

If I update the query to order by

```
select top 1 * from (
    select top 1 id from [user]
    union all
    select 0
) a order by id desc
```

Then I get the correct result of 1 in both SQL Server 2016 and 2017.

Is this the query optimizer seeing that 'select 0' is faster and returning the result?

Comment: It's not wrong, you don't have an `ORDER BY`. If you don't supply an `ORDER BY` clause the ordering is **never** guaranteed. Using `TOP 1` without an `ORDER BY` means you are happy expecting a "random" row from the dataset based on the optimiser's whims.

Comment: [No Seatbelt – Expecting Order without ORDER BY](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by/)

Comment: @SebastianBrosch ah nice find, thanks. We upgraded from 2005 > 2008 > 2012 > 2014 > 2016, and this code which has never changed, just broke in 2017. So I never came across this issue before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried with the `ORDER BY 1 DESC`?

It should solve the problem for both versions

```
select top 1 * from (
    select top 1 id from [user]
    union all
    select 0
) a ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: I'm sure if you had read my question you would have noticed I already mentioned adding an order by returned the correct results :/

Comment: yes i've noticed but it was column based (ID), i was wondering you didnt want to order by a specific column (e.g. if u have a dynamic sql). Anyway, if this doesnt answer your question, i think comments in your main post do that.

Comment: The code was written ~12 years ago so upgrading to each version of SQL Server has always worked, until last week. Just odd issue never seen before.